# Do all members of Yoda's species talk oddly?

Tags: star-wars, yoda

As we know, Yoda (the little green Jedi master in *Star Wars*) does not talk like most others. However, we know that Yoda is not the only one of his kind; a female member, also the same species, known as Yaddle, proved that Yoda was not the only one of his species. Therefore, I feel comfortable asking if all of Yoda's species speak backwards like him or if he's the only one.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151753/how-much-talk-like-yoda-yoda-actually-does

Comment: Should this question be titled “Talk oddly, do all of Yoda’s species?”

Comment: "In the shop it is" - Yaddle's line in, unfortunately, not canon [Yarael Poof material](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYVIs-Z1LM8)

Comment: Other (non-canon) members of the species not mentioned in answers or the question to research (see if they are known to speak oddly): the Jedi [Minch](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Minch), and [Vandar Tokare](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vandar_Tokare)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For reasons that are not clear, George Lucas required that no information about Yoda'a species was to be revealed in extended universe materials.  Up to this point, Disney has followed the same policy, although it is not clear whether that will continue to be a strict rule for the canon.

However, the net effect of Lucas's rules is that nobody knows what is typical of Yoda's species in essentially any regard.  Almost everything inferred about his race is simply based on observations of Yoda himself.  Yaddle has no dialogue, and what little is seen of her reveals essentially nothing that could not be inferred from observation of Yoda alone.  So whether Yoda's speech pattern is typical is completely unknown.

Comment: This just isn't right.  What about Yaddle?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Yaddle has no dialogue, and what is seen of her reveals essentially nothing that cannot be inferred from observation of Yoda alone.

Comment: It seems like quite an omission not to mention her given the decisive language used.  It leaves the impression that there is literally no information or appearance of anything at all to do with Yoda's species besides Yoda.   You can add pretty much what you just replied.

Answer (score 11):

In The Old Republic game, Master [Oteg](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Oteg) is also a yoda but speaks normally, not oddly.

> Welcome, my friends! I appreciate you all for coming all this way.

Unfortunately, the game is no longer considered canon:

https://www.starwars.com/news/swca-one-big-story-star-wars-canon-panel-liveblog#liveblog-entry-475

Answer (score 5):

Master [Yaddle](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yaddle) speaks perfectly in Basic.